# How to add text on top of images when sending html email using java common email API?

Tags: java, html, jsp, email, apache-commons

I am trying to send html email using a jsp page. I have worked on a code where i can embed images and send the email, but when trying to add images having text on them it did not work. 
The code is shown below: The main idea is the background image it is not working. All other css are working.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.mail.resolver.DataSourceUrlResolver"%>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String htmlEmailTemplate = ".... <img src=\"http://localhost:8080/SendEmail/background-plate.png\"> ....";
URL url = new URL("http://localhost");
ImageHtmlEmail email = new ImageHtmlEmail();
email.setDataSourceResolver(new DataSourceUrlResolver(url));
String authuser = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
String authpwd = "xxxxxx";
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));
email.setDebug(true);
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class",   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
email.setFrom("xxxxx@gmail.com", "SenderName");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setHtmlMsg(htmlEmailTemplate+"<h2>This is a test mail?</h2>"+"<div style=\"display: block;padding: 3;margin-right: 8px;margin-bottom: 16px;height: 41px;width: 170px;background-image: url('http://localhost:8080/SendEmail/background-plate.png');background-repeat: no-repeat;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Roadgeek2005SeriesERegular, Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;font-size: 32px; line-height: 48px;color: #000;font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none;\">ali123</div>");


email.addTo("xxxxxyyy@gmail.com", "ToName");

email.send();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The email being received is just showing the content of the div, rather than showing the image and content on top of it. What I should do to allow showing content in top of images?

Comment: When you write "The email is being received" what do you mean? Is it received locally at your pc? Have you verified with your browser that the image is reachable at the url you provided? Which mailclient do you use?

Comment: The idea to hardcode html template in the java code is awful.

Comment: I mean that I can send the email to any other email,not locally. Yes the image is reachable so if i try http://localhost:8080/SendEmail/background-plate.png it shows me the image. Also, i can include it on the mail but when used in css it doesn't show anything. I am using gmail and the jars I use are: activation, commons-mail, java-mail.